# Is it possible to solve tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix whose center element is different, using Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind?

Tags: chebyshev-polynomials

I have a tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix whose first diagonal below main diagonal, and the first diagonal above the main diagonal have elements equal to $-1$ and the main diagonal elements are same constants except at the middle element.

Can I solve the matrix analytically using Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind?

Comment: Hy by Solve you mean what?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. The system is like, K ϕ=δ, where K is the above mentioned tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix, ϕ is the column matrix of unknowns and δ is the column matrix with first element zero and all other elements zero. So, I want to know, is it possible to solve for ϕ by using Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind.

Comment: i guess the eigenvalues of such matrices are known, $0$ is not an eigenvalue in general